# Determining conditional probability given a dataset and a series of RVs

Tags: probability

So suppose I have a box of 5 biased coins where the P(H) is a r.v. (let's say for argument it could be 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 or 0.5).  I have a dataset of 10 trials - I record how long it takes for me to see my first H flip.  I can calculate the probability of the entire dataset given which coin I'm using, but I need to figure out the probability of each coin given the dataset.  I tried setting this up using Bayes' theorem [P(Cx|D) = P(D|Cx)P(Cx)/P(D)] I am stuck trying to figure out what P(D) (the probability of our dataset) is.  I feel like I don't have enough information to solve this but I might be missing something trivial!

Comment: Hint: you can use law of total probability to find $P(D)$ in terms of the different $P(D|C_x)$

Comment: LTP means we need the probabilities for Cx dont we?  It would be set up like P(D) = P(D|C1)P(C1) + P(D|C2)P(C2) + etc... correct?  I'm trying to solve for the P(C1/C2/C3), which is why I'm so stuck.

Comment: That's correct. Do you know the distribution of $P(H)$?